# Calculating assortativity in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I have a dataset as follows:

```
set.seed(123)
A = data.frame(rnorm(10),rnorm(10),rnorm(10),rnorm(10))
```

And then used igraph package to make a network out of the following:

```
inv<-cor(t(A))
inv[inv<0.5] <- 0
inv[inv==1] <- 0
g1 <- graph.adjacency(inv, mode = "undirected", diag=FALSE, weighted=TRUE)
```

Now to calculate the assortativity coefficeint of g1,

```
assortativity (g1, types1, types2 = NULL, directed = TRUE)
```

My question now is, how should I set "types", it says in the documentation, it is vertex values. What exactly is meant by that? I would like to calculate assortativity for any 5 vertex int he network. Could anyone tell me how this is done ?

Comment: ....assortativity based on what? The answer to this question might help you understand why there are types...

Comment: Based on a selected set of vertex (specific nodes in the network base don their vertex labels) for instance? Could you please show me how this could be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I guess you want the nominal version of assortativity. Eg.

```
V(g1)$foo <- sample(1:3, replace=TRUE, vcount(g1))
assortativity.nominal(g1, types=V(g1)$foo)
# [1] -0.2270916
```

Types must be integers starting from 1. See details in the documentation.

Comment: How would one do the same for a continuous variable for a directed graph? I have a measure of relatedness (ranges from 0 to 1) for both in and outgoing edges as two vectors, but I can't seem to add them to args types1 and types2.

Comment: You will need to discretise it I am afraid. AFAIK assortativity is not defined for continuous quantities. Although I can imagine that it is not too hard to generalize it.